# How to fix the LinkedIn share button error

Tags: linkedin-api

I use the LinkedIn share button in my web site, I use the same script to share the page to LinkedIn. However, some pages are successful. some pages fail.
This is error message

```
Error while processing route: inshare.index Ember Data Request GET /voyager/api/contentcreation/urlPreview/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.atpinc.com%2Fblog%2Fssd-data-retention-temperature-thermal-throttling returned a 500
Payload (application/json)
[object Object] Error: Ember Data Request GET /voyager/api/contentcreation/urlPreview/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.atpinc.com%2Fblog%2Fssd-data-retention-temperature-thermal-throttling returned a 500
Payload (application/json)
```

Comment: Mine was an issue with my own page. LinkedIn uses a BOT to hit that URL being shared with a user agent like "LinkedInBot". And my page had a special logic not to serve any bots and send a 403 response. Just in case someone stumbles upon such an issue in future.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want a more lightweight solution than the SDK?  All you need is:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

For example, this works for me:

> https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http://www.wikipedia.org/

Works fine:

[image]

Then just make your own button/icon/text for sharing.

If you are interested in a regularly maintained GitHub project that keeps track of this so you don't have to, check it out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]